# Is the level set of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ all the level curves for all constants $z$?

Tags: graphing-functions

Maybe an example would help explain.  If we sketch this graph it is a bowel shaped object and cut along the  horizon at some value of z = constant we get a level curve.  I am right so far?

This curve is a circle that is 2 dimensional and sits in 3 D space at the height z?

And if I have all the curves then they form the set ? True.?

Comment: Personally, I would say the set of all level curves of $f(x,y)$ or simply the surface of $f(x,y)$ to avoid confusion, but I believe you've got the right idea

Comment: The level sets are subsets of the $(x,y)$ plane, the don't live in $(x,y,z)$ space.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=c$ gives you the circle of radius $\sqrt{c}$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. This is the level set (in this case, curve) for the value $c$. Note that the general definition of the level set of a real valued function $f : \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ at $c \in \Bbb{R}$ is $ \{ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid f(x_1, \dots, x_n)= c \} $. Note how in our case, the points of the level set will be living in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: nice explanation...how does this compare to let us say a level curve ? is here a difference ?

Comment: A level curve is just the special case of a level set when the domain of the function is $\Bbb{R}^2$.